# How do I use while function to complete this question

Tags: python

For example, if user keys in 6, the output is 21 (1+2+3+4+5+6)

sum = 0
num = int(input("Enter number: "))
…..
….

This is my code below:

```
x=0
sum = 0
nums = int(input("enter num "))
while sum <= nums:
    sum+=1
    x= x + sum
y = x - nums -1
print(y)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, I suggest not to use `sum` as variable name, this will shadow the built-in `sum()` function.

There are two ways to do it using while loop, the first one is close to yours but turn `<=` to `<` in the condition so you don't need extra `- num - 1` at the end.

```
n = 0
total = 0
num = int(input("enter num "))
while n < num:
    n += 1
    total += n
print(total)
```

Second one adds number in descending order, it also change the value of `num`. If you need `num` for later use, use the first one.

```
total = 0
num = int(input("enter num "))
while num:
    total += num
    num -= 1
print(total)
```

If loop is not needed, as you are going to obtain a [triangular number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number), just use the formula.

```
num = int(input("enter num "))
print(num * (num + 1) // 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have use a loop you could do it in a single line:

```
print(sum(range(1, int(input('Enter a number: ')) + 1)))
```

Test:

```
Enter a number: 6
21
```